# project Euler #12 - Difference between the two codes' performance

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I have recently begun learning python and in order to familiarise myself with the concepts I began solving Euler's problem. I have been trying to solve [Euler's problem number 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) however my code runs for a long period of time (Greater than 10 minutes and still running). I checked online and ran this piece of code, surprisingly it took only 11 seconds. But I am unable to understand the difference between the two. Really appreciate if someone could help me understand the difference

my code #1:

```
from time import time
import math

def divisors(n):
    n = int(n)
    sqrt = int(math.sqrt(n))
    result = sum(2 for i in range(1, sqrt+1) if n%i == 0)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i**2 == n:
            result = result - 1
    return result
i = 1
num = 0
a = 0
t = time()
while a < 500:
    num = num+i
    print(num, i)
    i = i+1
    a = divisors(num)
print(a)
tt = time() - t
print(tt)
```

my code #2

```
from time import time
import math

def divisors(n):
    n = int(n)
    sqrt = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result = sum(2
                     for i in range(1, sqrt+1) if n%i == 0)
        if i**2 == n:
            result = result - 1
    return result

i = 1
num = 0
a = 0
t = time()
while a < 500:
    num = num+i
    print(num, i)
    i = i+1
    a = divisors(num)
print(a)
tt = time() - t
print(tt)
```

Code which took 11 seconds:

```
import math
from time import time
t = time()
def divisors(n):
    number_of_factors = 0
    for i in range(1, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))):
        if n % i == 0:
            number_of_factors +=2
        else:
            continue
    return number_of_factors

x=1
for y in range(2,1000000):
    x += y
    if divisors(x) >= 500:
        print x
        break
tt = time()-t
print tt
```

Comment: your code #2 computes `result` in the loop, should be outside the loop.

Comment: What about code#1?

Answer (score 0):

its better to ask this question with algorithm tag.

anyway, difference is in implementation of function divisors.

for `divisors(n)` complexity of this function in your codes are O(n) cause of this line: 

`for i in range(1, n+1):`

but in third code the complexity of `divisors(n)`is O(sqrt(n))

you can improve your code with editing `divisors` function

my hint: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n*(n + 1) / 2 and it cant be perfect square...

Comment: OMG yes! Sigh, such a stupid mistake! Thank you, I will try what you said.